# Word for "Putting a Lot of People in One Place"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word, preferably a verb, that means that keeping a large group of people in a small confined space?

For example, the US government "kept" a large number of child migrants at its detention centre. What more informative word should we use to replace the generic word "kept"?

Comment: Closely related: [idiom or word for a very crowded place](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143782/idiom-or-word-for-a-very-crowded-place/144037#144037)

Comment: "Housed" I believe is a more accurate word. Your request to replace the word "kept" is very different then trying to insinuate a position on quantity of persons being included.  There is a distinction and as written, the statement "a large number" makes it clear there are a lot. replacing "kept" with a word indicating quantity would repeat the statement.

Comment: Do you  want a negatively connoted term?

Comment: *adj. overcrowded*

Comment: Beware of hyperbole in a number of the answers, unless that's what you're going for.

Comment: the word you are looking for is _housed_ (regarding the last question)

Comment: to answer your first question it is _crammed_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know why I can't find an appropriate dictionary definition (it's not even in the full Oxford English Dictionary), but...

> *[Many child migrants] [were **coralled** in](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22were%20coralled%20in%22) [a detention centre].*

Even though I can't find a definition, there are lots of matches for the highlighted search string, so the intended sense is obvious.

---

EDIT:
Ooops! My bad spelling (but given the "lots of matches" I found in Google Books, I don't feel *too* embarrassed! :) ...

> **corral** (noun) <sup><sub>Merriam-Webster</sub></sup>
> *a pen or enclosure for confining or capturing livestock*

> **corral** (transitive verb)
> *to enclose in a corral*

...which regardless of whether it's ***corralled*** or (far less common) ***corraled***, still gets far more hits in Google Books than my completely mis-spelled version above.

---

A more recent term specifically used in the context of (riot) police packing protesters into a small, easily-controlled space...

> [**kettle**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59485/what-is-the-sense-of-the-word-kettle-here)
> ***Kettling** (also known as **containment** or **corralling**) is a police tactic for controlling large crowds during demonstrations or protests. It involves the formation of large cordons of police officers who then move **to contain a crowd within a limited area**.*

---

But no-one seems to have mentioned the obvious choice...

> *The US government **confined** a large number of child migrants at its detention centre.*

Comment: I'd guess the less-common _corraled_ is a US variant.  But I've always associated _corral_ with the Wild West, suggesting that should be more common.  There's really no need to keep your initial wrong spelling in the answer - I tried to edit, but the change was too far-reaching for anyone except yourself to get right!

Comment: I was initially going to distinguish the two different spellings as AmE and BrE in my answer text (as with *traveled, cancelled,* etc.). But a quick check on NGrams made it obvious that this is one case where the single-L spelling is uncommon even in the AmE corpus, so I contented myself with ***far less common***.

Comment: "Corral" implies driving livestock to a pen and penning them (driving as opposed to anything violent). Metaphorically, it means bringing disparate things or ideas together to a small place. It does not imply any particular crowding.

Comment: @fectin: Nonsense. No less than *three* words in the short M-W definition *(**pen, enclosure, confining**)* all strongly imply "crowding" into a limited area. It's effectively oxymoronic to speak of ***people being corralled into a large area***.

Comment: @TobySpeight Even in American English, root-final <l> is doubled when in a stressed syllable (cf. _excel_ and _appal_, both of which get doubled <ll> in both AmE and BrE), so you wouldn’t expect there to be any non-doubled forms at all. Perhaps it’s because there’s some variation in whether the last syllable has a long or short vowel (/æl/ or /ɑːl/) in this particular word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I thought that since the second syllable always carries the stress in ***corral***, it would have to be a "long" vowel. But the dominant orthography certainly does seem to buck the trend here. Maybe the potential confusion with (poetic) ***coralled*** (covered with coral) is a factor?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don’t quite follow – there are plenty of verbs with second-syllable stress and short vowels (excel, expel, repel, rappel, instil, fulfil, etc.). It is true that /-æl/ is quite a rare ending, though, especially for verbs – _corral_ and _canal_ appear to be the only ones. Although the OED says _canal_ follows the general pattern of doubling in BrE and not doubling in AmE, Ngrams indicate that doubling forms are in fact more common for both words, indicating that vowel length isn’t necessarily indicative.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I thought ***to coral*** would primarily be ***to cover with coral***, but the full OED only has it as a rare verb meaning ***to make red** (like coral)*. Anyway, it's really strange that the US/UK difference should be so much less with the verb ***to canal*** than with ***to coral***. Maybe something to do with how common (*rare*, with ***to canal***) the usages are?

Comment: For me, _corralling_ evokes the act of driving the people into an enclosure, and _corralled_ evokes being driven, while _packed_ as requested by the OP instead evokes the (resulting) state, not the act that led to this state.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Well, you can ***pack*** just about anything from sardines to clothes into a small space. But in *British* English we never even used either the noun or the verb ***corral*** in respect of horses, so just about the *only* "victims / patients / objects" that might be corralled in BrE are ("victimised") *people*.

Comment: Re:  "confined" being the obvious choice - that just means being put somewhere one cannot leave, not necessarily that the place is small or crowded. If I don't have a passport I am effectively confined to the United Kingdom, and while the UK may be small by US standards I certainly wouldn't want to travel the whole thing on foot.

Comment: @Spratty: That's your opinion, which you're entitled to hold. But apparently, even though [*More Britons travelled abroad last year (2018) than any other nationality, according to official data*](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/british-travellers-iata-world-air-transport-statistics-a9029366.html), 15% of Britons have *never* been abroad (and strong swimmers can cross the English Channel, ***and*** tens of thousands make it *into* the country in rubbishy little inflatables). And yet many of us would *still* say *How can you be "confined" in a place as big as Great Britain?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I tend to agree with you in principle; I completely understand people associating small spaces with confinement, but nonetheless it doesn't _necessarily_ mean that so I couldn't recommend it be used for that purpose. It's no more than a technical quibble, but if someone's looking for a definitive answer I get twitchy if one of the suggestions is even technically inappropriate. As for being "confined in a place as big as Great Britain?", well, technically mankind is currently confined to the area inside the orbit of the moon, and may be permanently confined to the solar system.

Comment: @Spratty: The Apollo 8 astronauts were the first humans to ***see the far side in person*** when they orbited the Moon in 1968. So even though they didn't land and go for a walk, I suppose technically speaking mankind has been slightly *beyond* the orbit of the moon. But I won't say "already", given how long ago that was, and *still* no-one has *landed* on the far side. Anyway, as regards the exact meaning of "confined" - obviously strictly speaking you're right (mankind must surely be "confined" to the "visible universe" forever, even if we're quite certain there's more space *beyond* that).

Comment: ...but that doesn't justify encouraging nns to be more "correct, precise" than native speakers! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: re the Apollo astronauts, that's why I said "currently" - as far as I understand it, no-one can, today, this very instant, launch and exceed the moon's orbit. Maybe in a few months, but not today. And as for "that doesn't justify encouraging nns to be more "correct, precise" than native speakers!" - where I live (S.E. Essex, UK), it would be easy to argue that most non-native speakers are _already_ more correct and precise than many of the native speakers :-)

Answer (score 41):

If you want to stress the idea of many people [packed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/packed) into  a confined space you can use ***[cram](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cram)***:

> to force a lot of things into a small space:
>
> *Eight children were crammed into the back of the car.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: this was my first thought, but cram does seem to have a positive image "it was a great night out we were crammed in, such an atmosphere"

Comment: @WendyG - not sure there is anything positive about people  crammed  into a confined space.

Comment: Your "packed into" is good in its own right.

Answer (score 10):

***Squash***

> If people or things are ***squashed** into a place*, they are put or pushed into a place where there is not enough room for them to be.
>
> - There were 2000 people *squashed* into her recent show. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/squash))

Comment: My house is a squash and a squeeze. (Julia Donaldson)

Answer (score 7):

A word with positive connotations is [**gather**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gather), which can be transitive:

> : to bring together : **collect**
>
> *tried to gather a crowd*

Or intransitive:

> : to come together in a body
>
> : to cluster around a focus of attraction

A word with negative connotations is [**concentrate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concentrate), also either transitive or intransitive.

> : to bring or direct toward a common center or objective : **focus**
>
> : gather, collect
>
> *Cuban immigrants who concentrate in Florida*

Beware; this could be, in context, much too pejorative.  The Nazi death camps were “concentration camps.”

Comment: Presumably the term _concentration camp_, as used in the Boer war and for the Nazi forced-labour and execution sites, originates from exactly this meaning?

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes. Regardless of the etymology, however, the term “concentration camp” is now too strongly associated with the Holocaust to be used in its early-20th-century meaning. (Similarly, “eugenics” and “euthanasia” originally meant something else before the Nazis used them as euphemisms.)

Comment: @TobySpeight And thanks for catching my typo.

Comment: Oh, I agree about the connotations; just musing on the etymology.  I should learn to keep my internal voice where it belongs...

Comment: I'd note Nazi death camps are "extermination camps", built with the explicit purpose of the mass murder of Jews. They're distinct from concentration camps.

Answer (score 6):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sardine#:%7E:text=Merriam%2C%201913) (here amended slightly) lists 'sardine' as a verb, and includes the picturesque broadened, arguably informal, sense:

> **sardine** ... [verb] ...
>
> - to fish for sardines
> - [transitive] to pack or cram together tightly [usually used with a PP, eg 'into the small room']
>
> .........
>
> - [1986, The New Yorker - Vol  62]:
>
> *Would it be unbearably elitist to suggest that they would be more enjoyable still if the director removed a row or two of chairs,
> instead of sardining as many listeners as possible into the intimate
> music room?*
>
> - [2007, Julie Kavanagh, Nureyev: The Life]:
>
> *There were already six members of the Nureyev family living in a room sixteen meters square, the children sardined on one mattress on the
> floor, their parents separated by only a curtain.*

Another verb that could be used here is *shoehorn* [[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoehorn)]:

> **shoehorn** [verb] [transitive]
>
> - to fit something or someone into a tight place:
>
> .........
>
> - *We’d have to build another school to shoehorn all our students in.*

- *A large number of child migrants were shoehorned / sardined into the detention centre.*

Neither of these suggested verbs strongly implies 'kept over an extended period'.

Comment: "shoehorn" has the connotation of adding a small amount of new... whatever it is, to a space that is already nearly full. The idea of "fitting" is also often inherently understood to be metaphorical rather than literal. You could say that you're "shoehorning" one more child migrant into a detention centre that is already full of them, but it sounds like looking for an excuse for holding the child there, rather than physically making room. In any event it doesn't make sense for describing the overall process.

Answer (score 6):

If your point is that they were kepy very close together, you could say that they were kept **shoulder to shoulder.** [Collins defines this as follows:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shoulder-to-shoulder)

> If two or more people stand shoulder to shoulder, they are standing next to each other, with their shoulders touching.

Comment: A more vulgar equivalent is “nuts to butts”.

Answer (score 1):

### Concentrate

> to bring or come together in one place

> ETYMOLOGY: 17c: from Latin con- together + centrum centre.

Source: [Chambers Dictionary](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=concentrate&title=21st)

This is the sense of the word which gives us 'Concentration Camp', which originally meant

> A camp for the concentration and temporary accommodation of large numbers of troops awaiting active service.

Source: [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/403843?redirectedFrom=concentration%20camp#eid) (membership login required)

and more frequently now means

> a prison camp used to detain civilians who are not tolerated by the authorities, especially in Nazi Germany.

Source: [Chambers Dictionary](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=concentration%20camp&title=21st)

Answer (score 1):

## stuffed

> *Child migrants were **stuffed** into detention centres*

1. fill (a receptacle or space) tightly with something.
2. force or cram (something) tightly into a receptacle or space.
3. [informal] hastily force (something) into a space.

Oxford English Dictionary